SPM: How to set assets and its related code inside a package, only available for specific target?
I have assets in my package which i only need for main target and the other code that may be added to multiple targets but that don't need the assets at all. If i add the package to multiple targets   app size is increased unnecessarily.
And since it is a UI specific package I also don't want to create separate package for this alone since it is a. Is there any way this could be achieved?.
